# incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String?

Tags: java

I am currently new to Java and have no prior programming experience, I am currently trying to code a solution to a problem proposed during my university interview :)

```
//Winner rabbit variable to hold the winner of the 'race'
    String winner;
    winner = yettoracequeue.element();
```

Background about problem:

1. assign the first item in queue to a string variable
2. remove first item from queue
3. assign the second item in queue to another string variable
4. compare both variables and assign the answer to a new variable

I do not understand why yettoracequeue.element() is considered an object when the result is a string, e.g. Rabbit, and hence I am unable to assign it to the String variable that is winner.

TIA :)

Edit:

This is the full code

```
package queuepart;
import java.util.*;
public class QueuePart {

  static String nextline = System.getProperty("line.separator");

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Step 1: Create LinkedList() to assign to yettoracequeue
    Queue yettoracequeue = new LinkedList();

    //Step 2: add rabbits to queue
    int rabbitno = 1;
    yettoracequeue.add("Rabbit" + rabbitno);
    rabbitno++; 
    yettoracequeue.add("Rabbit" + rabbitno);
    rabbitno++; 
    yettoracequeue.add("Rabbit" + rabbitno);
    rabbitno++; 
    yettoracequeue.add("Rabbit" + rabbitno);
    rabbitno++; 
    yettoracequeue.add("Rabbit" + rabbitno);
    rabbitno++; 
    yettoracequeue.add("Rabbit" + rabbitno);

    System.out.println(nextline + "Items in the queue" + yettoracequeue + nextline);

    //Find first item in queue
    System.out.println(nextline + "First item in queue is " + yettoracequeue.element());

    //Assign First item in queue to racer
    String winner = yettoracequeue.element();

  }
}
```

Comment: What type is `yettoracequeue`?

Comment: A `Rabbit` class is not a `String`

Comment: Please show your code for element() method of yettoracequeue

Comment: I got the element()  method from the queue documentation over here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Comment: According to what I've read, rabbit should be of the object type /:

Comment: @Anmol I have added the rest of my code to the OP.

Comment: @Mureinik forgot to tag you in the previous reply/:

Also, I remember seeing an answer from another user while on mobile but now it's gone, how do I see it again? I didn't delete it /:

Thanks!

Comment: don't use raw types, use `Queue<String> yettoracequeue = new LinkedList<>()`, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a typecast:

```
    winner = (String) yettoracequeue.element();
```

---

Explanation: the way you have declared the `yettoracequeue` variable, what you have is a `Queue` of objects; that is, a queue that *could* contain any kind of object.  You have added `String` objects to the queue, but you could have put any type of object into it.

So when you call `yettoracequeue.element()`, the compiler only knows that the object is going to be an instance of `java.lang.Object` or some subclass.  (That is because every object is an instance of `java.lang.Object` or some subclass!)

But when you assign the value to `winner`, the system needs to know that the object you assign is really a `String`.  (If it was something else, then `String` specific operations on it would not work.)

So what does the type-cast do?

Well `(String) yettoracequeue.element()` does a runtime type check.  It checks that the object returned by the method call is really a String:

- If the runtime type check succeeds, then it treats the type of the expression as `String` ... and the assignment is valid.
- If the runtime type check fails, then the runtime system throws a `ClassCastException` ... and your program will typically fail.

---

Actually, there is a better way to solve the problem in this particular case.  The `Queue` type is actually a generic type; i.e. you can give it a type parameter.  It looks like this:

```
    Queue<String> yettoracequeue = new LinkedList<>();
```

I have now declared that `yettoracequeue` is a queue that contains `String` objects.  If I do that then:

- When I try to add (say) an `Integer` object to the queue, I will get a compilation error.
- When I call `yettoracequeue.element()` the compiler will know that the queue only contains `String` objects, and won't insist on the type cast when I assign the result to a `String` variable.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. :)  

Does (String) actually convert the result of yettoracequeue.element() into a string? Or does it actually only check if it is a string and proceed if it is?  

I've seen the 2nd suggestion somewhere else on stackoverflow too but i'm currently using strings to test if my queue works before changing the queue of strings into a queue of objects later on, which I imagine I will run into plenty of problems :P  </br>
  
Thanks again!

Comment: It checks to see that it is already a String.  No conversion ... in the sense you mean.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that the queue is a raw type as opposed to a queue *of String*. To avoid the type error, you have to provide the generic type argument:

```
Queue<String> yettoracequeue = new LinkedList<String>();
   // ^^^^^^
```

You can read more about Generic Types in the [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).