# Java 8 stream: convert comma separated string to the list of abstract Enum

Tags: java, list, intellij-idea, enums, java-stream

Is it possible to convert a comma separated string to the list of `java.lang.Enum` by using stream?

My original code is the following, which is working:

```
List<String> inValuesStr = Arrays.asList(criteria.getValue().toString().split(","));
List<Enum> inValues = new ArrayList<>();
for (String val : inValuesStr){
    inValues.add(Enum.valueOf(path.getType(),val));
}
```

I tried to refactor it to be as code below:

```
List<Enum> inValues = Arrays.stream(criteria.getValue().toString().split(","))
    .map(v -> Enum.valueOf(path.getType(),v))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Looks very basic... but, the following compile-time error is shown:

```
Error:(--, --) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.Enum>
```

I can't understand where is the mistake. Did someone had the same experience? Thanks for sharing a solution.

Comment: `eclipse` issue may be? what does `javac` report?

Comment: `Enum.valueOf` probably returns an Object. Therefore `collect()` returns a `List<Object>` and it's incompatible with `List<Enum>`. 
What is the type of `path.getType()` ?

Comment: It works alright for me too, but I don't use the same valueOf definition with two parameters

Comment: @Arnaud Claudel. It can be any enum type. For example, I have a Person entity which has a field sex, which is Sex enum. So this code is inside of an generic function that should convert list of string values `criteria.getValue()` to the list of specific type of enum `path.getType()`. What is interesting is that if I remove abstraction, it works `List<Sex> inValues = Arrays.stream(criteria.getValue().toString().split(","))
                        .map(v -> Sex.valueOf(v))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());` But, I would like to keep it abstract

Comment: changes `List<Enum>` to `List<Type>`

Comment: show your _entire_ code that we can re-produce, not long comments; voting to close for now.

Comment: @Eugene, maybe you are right. But instead I'm using intellij. I tried to build the project via command line and the build was successful. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @andriy I guess you need to add a type witness somewhere, but are you sure you are using the latest IntelliJ? this would be very weird...

Comment: @Eugene, It is in fact weird! I just added `(List<Enum>)` after '=' and it works! But intellij itself suggest me to remove this cast by saying that it is redundant. The version I'm using is `IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.7 (Ultimate Edition) built on November 26, 2018`.

Comment: there are much newer ones, can you try that?

Comment: You should show the signature of `getType()`

Comment: @Eugene, just finished updating. So it is now at `IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.8 (Ultimate Edition) built on March 28, 2019` and same thing. However, I can't update further as some plugins are incompatible. It is better if I contact their support... it is not a java issue

Comment: This sounds precisely what you get with JDK 8 when `getType()` returns the raw type `Class` (or when `path` has a raw type). Whereas newer JDKs handle it slightly differently. But generally, you should avoid raw types.

Comment: Take a look here — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374892/incompatible-types-java-lang-object-cannot-be-converted-to-java-lang-string.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
enum Ascii {
    A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z;
}

private void test() throws InterruptedException {
    List<String> inValuesStr = Arrays.asList("A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N".split(","));
    List<Ascii> list = inValuesStr.stream()
        .map(s -> Ascii.valueOf(s))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: He uses `path.getType()` as first parameter of `Enum::valueOf`. This doesn't answer the question at all

Comment: @YassinHajaj Works just the same with `Enum.valueOf(Ascii.class, s)`

Comment: I suspect the problem here is that `path.getType()` returns `Class<?>`, not `Class<? extends Enum>`.  Using `path.getType().asSubclass(Enum.class)` (and potentially casting the result of the `Enum.valueOf` call...) should get around this.

Comment: @user2478398 not with `Class<?>`, but with the raw type `Class`. But in that case, `asSubclass` won’t help as the result of a generic operation on a raw type will be again a raw type.